# How can I export my scraped data from a list to my csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I can't seem to correctly export my data into a single variable an export this variable to a csv file. What am I doing wrong?

I tried:

```py
csvFile = open('products.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
writer.writerow(('name', 'price'))

url = 'https://www.ah.nl/producten/aardappel-groente-fruit/groente/merk=AH'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(100)

def itemGrabber(url):
    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product')
    print(str(len(items)) + " items found on page.")

    item = []
    for i in items:
        ## name of product
        t = i.find_element_by_class_name('product-description__title').text.replace("\xad", "")

        ## price
        p = i.find_element_by_class_name('product-price').text

        item.append(t)

        item.append(p)


    print(item)

    return item

products = itemGrabber(url)
writer.writerow(products)

csvFile.close()
```

the result in the csv is:

```
name,price

yoghurt,1.0,banana,2.0,kinkytoy,6.99
```

And I want it to be categorized correctly. I tried converting t and p to lists and adding them to the variable 'item', but this is even worse. Can you give me tips how to make it better? Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it directly as a row into csv instead of using collections.

```
def itemGrabber(url):
    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product')
    print(str(len(items)) + " items found on page.")

    for i in items:
        ## name of product
        t = i.find_element_by_class_name('product-description__title').text.replace("\xad", "")

        ## price
        p = i.find_element_by_class_name('product-price').text
        writer.writerow((t, p))


products = itemGrabber(url)
```

Comment: Thanks Sureshmani, do you think I could do this more efficiently? Id like to learn more methods of exporting data

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this a lot more efficiently with a more high level library like pandas.

But what you're really missing is a way to tell your csvwriter where the row breaks are and you're writing the entire array as a single row.

Consider changing

```
 item.append(t)
 item.append(p)
```

to

```
 item.append([t,p])
```

and then changing your writer code `writer.writerow(products)`

```
for product in products:
    writer.writerow(product)
```

Comment: Thanks man, pandas is my next goal, I feel like I need to get the basics right first! Would you recommend creating a dictionary instead of the list method I used?